# Finding saddle point in a binary tree using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I want to find a saddle point of T, binary tree, if there is one.
saddle point has minimum value among all its ancestors, but it has maximum value among all its descendants.  A leaf can be such a saddle point, if it has a lower value than all of it's ancestors.

Example tree:

```
              F:15
         E:16        H:17
    B:14         G:16    I:8
 A:8    C:7
           D:5
```

B is one such saddle point because 14 is less than 16 and 15, but also greater than 8, 7, and 5.  A, C, D, and I are the other saddle points.

I tried to think of way to recursively check the each sub trees and prove that parent node is the maximum among all its descendants. But, since C (16) is a maximum among all its descendants but greater than F (15), it is not a saddle point, so this method is incorrect.

What would be the best way to solve it.?

Comment: A,B,C,I are saddle points.

Comment: yes, A,B,C,I,D. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function `find_saddle` that takes a node, and the minimum value of the parents (defaulting to `INT_MAX` for the root node).  It will return the value of the largest child.  When the function is called, it figures out the largest value a child can have and potentially be a saddle, the min of itself and the minimum parent.  It then recurses with that minimum down the left and right and recieves the maximum values in each subtree.  If the node's own value is greater than bolth subtree's max's but less than the parent's minimums, then it's a saddle and does... whatever you want.  Finally, it returns the maximum of it's own value and both subtree maximums.

```
int find_saddle(node* n, int parent_min=INT_MAX) {
   int child_min = min(n->value, parent_min);

   int left_max = INT_MIN;
   if (n->left)
       left_max = find_saddle(n->left, child_min);

   int right_max= INT_MIN;
   if (n->right) 
       right_max = find_saddle(n->right, child_min);

   int child_max = max(left_max, right_max); 

   if (n->value > child_max && n->value < parent_min)
       do_thing(n);

   return max(child_max, n->value);
}
```

This code assumes that leaves can be saddle points, but it's not super hard to tweak it to exclude those nodes.

Comment: can you briefly explain what does '(n->left ? find_saddle(n->left, child_min) : INT_MIN)' do? I am not familiar with ( A ? B(A,..) : C)..

Comment: @BBbbBB: The expression `x = A ? B : C` is very nearly identical to `if (A) x=B; else x=C;`.  I've simplified the code to be clearer.